# Is intelligence an innate quality of Brahmanas?

Tags: caste-system, brahmins

According to Hindu scriptures, different castes were created differently and therefore have different innate qualities.

For example, Kshatriyas are strong according to the *Taittiriya Samhita*:

> **[7.1.1](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv07.htm)** - After it the god Indra was created, the Tristubh metre, the Brhat Saman, **of men the Rajanya**, of cattle the sheep. **Therefore they are strong, for they were created from strength.**

The *Bhagavad Gita* gives a more detailed list of the qualities of each caste.

For Brahmanas it says:

> **[18.42](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/18/42/)** - Peacefulness, self-control, austerity, purity, tolerance, honesty, knowledge, wisdom and religiousness – these are the natural qualities by which the brāhmaṇas work.

Now my question is whether Brahmanas *innately* have a high IQ. In other words, were Brahmanas created to be intelligent, just like how Kshatriyas were created to be strong and have a high pain tolerance?

The Sanskrit word used for "wisdom" in that verse is vijñānam, but can it also mean "intelligence"?

Is there any verse in any scripture that explicitly states that Brahmanas are innately intelligent?

Comment: intelligence or medha is a part of wisdom, and so that is automatically implied.

Comment: They were created from brahma's mouth and so they were intelligent.All others were created from brahma's lower part.